# Save output of every command to separate log files?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I would like to `tee` output of every interactively executed command to a series of separate log files, one for each command. To do so, I have written the following script which will be set up as the last thing to run on shell startup (the end of `.bashrc`):

```
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
randstr=$(cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 4)
dir=~/log/"${date}_${randstr}"
mkdir "$dir"
i=0
while :
do
    read -e -p "user@host:$(pwd)\$ " cmd
    eval "$cmd 2>&1 | tee \"${dir}/${i}-${cmd}\"" 
    (( i++ ))
done
```

However there are some problems with this. First of all, this will stop reading as soon as a newline is encountered, simply because that's how `read` works. I don't want this behavior. I want it to behave exactly as a shell, so that for example when I write `ls &&` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>, it will wait for more input before executing anything.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible/feasible to achieve this with shell scripting? Should I use a more conventional programming language? Should I even patch `bash` to achieve this?

Comment: Try the `-d ''` option of `read` which skips past newlines.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may want to look into using `mktemp` for creating your temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
# teeshell

date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
randstr=$(cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 4)
dir="$(echo ~/log/"${date}_${randstr}")"
mkdir "$dir"
# Redirect everything to tee and perl
exec 1> >(tee /dev/tty |
          perl -pe '                                                                          
            sub reopen {
              open(OUT,">'$dir'/".++$i);
              select OUT;
              $| = 1;
            }                     
            BEGIN {
              `echo $$ > "'$dir'"/pid`;
              reopen();                                       
              $SIG{HUP} = \&reopen;                                                           
            }') 2>&1

# wait for perl to save the pid
while [ ! -f "$dir"/pid ] ; do
    true
done

# Magic! Make perl save to a new file with a kill -HUP
PS1="[\$(kill -HUP `cat "$dir"/pid`)][\u@\h:\w]\$ "
```

Run:

```
. teeshell
```